# "Would", being the short version of "would like to" here?

Tags: modal-verbs

> **Would** can be used to describe what people are willing to do. This can also be seen as including an unspoken condition.
>
> Tony **would** lend you his  car.   (...  if you  asked  him  ...)
>
> Only a real fan **would** pay that much for a ticket
>   (Only if someone was a fan would they pay ...)
>
> --Page 78 (Macmillan - Inside Out English Grammar in Context Advanced)

Is this particular usage of "would" normal to see or hear?

Can I think of "would" here as being the short version of "would like to"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an elliptical or shortened version of *would like to*. It is rather a different, older sense of *will* meaning *be willing to*.

The modal auxiliary verb *will* developed from an Old English lexical verb which meant approximately *want, desire*.  Today the modal has three distinct senses:

- *futurive*, signifying future time reference

  > Tomorrow John **will** go to London.
  >   John said yesterday that he **would** finish the job when he finds time.
- *dynamic*, signifying persistent action

  > When I was a child I **would** often read for hours every day.
  >   If you ***will*** keep teasing her you must expect her to get angry. (*In this use, where it means approximately "If you insist on teasing her"*, will *is strongly stressed.*)
- *volitive*, signifying willingness

  > If they **would** only listen they might learn something.
  >   If you **will** bring beer, I **will** bring chips.

The *dynamic* and *volitive* uses may include future reference.

Comment: Bottom line: _like_ indicates desire, and _would_ doesn't have that connotation.

Comment: I got it. I mixed "willingness" with "desire". My mistake! @jimsug

Comment: The *would=desire* sense was more common in Shakespeare's day - [*"I would you were set, so your affection would cease."*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+would+you+were+set+so+your+affection+would+cease%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=%22I+would+you+were+set+so+your+affection+would+cease%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59.12390593j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). I like that passage because a couple of lines later he has "Speed" rubbishing "Valentine's" love letters by asking *"Are they not **lamely** writ?"* There's certainly nothing lame about Shakespeare's use of the vernacular!