# Will in adverbial clause

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

I know the present tense should be used for an adverbial clause starting with "When," as in: When I become an adult, I will be a responsible person. But, I've read comments about exceptions, particularly involving "to be" in a when clause. So, is the following acceptable?

When I will be an adult, I am going to be a responsible person.

Comment: That *when-clause* in your sentence is a dependent clause, and *when* is used as a subordinating conjunction. You shouldn't use *will* there. For more information about this please refer to this [answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/4494/3463).

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of this kind of usage of *will*: [I'll give you 100 pounds if it'll help you to go on holiday](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/36527/3281).

Comment: I just found that StoneyB had summarized it nicely in [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24559/3281). Look under the *dynamic* and *volitive* senses.

Answer (score 1):

There are two somewhat different uses of *when* clauses with future reference.

In cases where the action of the main clause is cast in the future and you use the *when* clause to identify the future point more specifically, the *when* clause is cast in the present tense—it 'borrows' its tense reference from the main clause:

> Kevin will go to London when he <s>will have</s> **has** the time. ... *When will Kevin go to London? —When he has the time.*
>   I am going to be a responsible person when I <s>will be</s> **am** an adult. ... *When will you be a responsible person? —When I am an adult.*

But in cases where the future point is identified and you use the *when* clause to provide information about something else which will happen or be in effect at that time, you may use *will* or *BE going to* in the *when* clause:

> Kevin will go to London on Tuesday, when he **will have** the time. ... *Why will Kevin go on Tuesday? —Because that is when he will have the time.*
>   I am going to be a responsible person starting on my 21st birthday, when I **will be** an adult. ... *Why will you start being responsible then? —Because I will be an adult.*

This is essentially the difference between restrictive and non-restrictive relative clauses; we have [many questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=restrictive%20clause) which address that distinction.